# show panel with registerstartupscript

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

```
 <asp:Panel ID="filterBanners" runat="server" Visible ="false"> 
    <h3> Testing </h3>
 </asp:Panel>
```

I'm trying to set the panel visibility to true in this way, but it doesn't work:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ScriptBlock", "$('#filterBanners').show();", true);
```

or

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "ShowCode5", "$('#filterBanners').show();", true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id `filterBanners` of the Panel would be changed by asp.net for generated *html* so jQuery wont find it. you need to use the `ClientID` instead of server id in jQuery / javascript to access the Panel.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), 
  "ScriptBlock", "$('#"+ filterBanners.ClientID+"').show();", true);
```

If you have .net framework then you can also set [ClientIDMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx) to "static" to let the asp.net keep the client id same as server id.

[ClientIDMode = Static](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The ClientID value is set to the value of the ID property. If the
>   control is a naming container, the control is used as the top of the
>   hierarchy of naming containers for any controls that it contains.

You can also use class selector for panel but you will need to assign class to your Panel first.

*HTML*

```
 <asp:Panel ID="filterBanners" runat="server" CssClass="panel-class" Visible ="false"> 
    <h3> Testing </h3>
 </asp:Panel>
```

*Code behind*

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ScriptBlock", "$('.panel-class').show();", true);
```

**Edit 1**

Note you have to ensure that jQuery is loaded before your script executed, try using the native javascript method to access panel.

**Edit 2**

You are hiding the panel by setting `visible="false"` in html which will **result in no html generated for the panel so javascript could not find the panel**. You have to set its visible property to true in html to generate `html` for it.

The following code is **tested and working**.

*HTML*

```
 <asp:Panel ID="filterBanners" runat="server" Visible ="true"> 
     <h3> Testing </h3>
 </asp:Panel>
```

*Code behind*

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "ScriptBlock", 
 "document.getElementById('" + filterBanners.ClientID + 
 "') .style.display='none';", true);
```

**Edit 3**

If you want the panel initially hidden and you want to show it from server then do not use server side property visible="false" instead use style="display:none;" in html.

*HTML*

```
<asp:Panel ID="filterBanners" runat="server" style="display:none;"> 
    <h3> Testing </h3>
</asp:Panel>
```

*Code behind*

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "ScriptBlock", 
 "document.getElementById('" + filterBanners.ClientID + 
 "').style.display='block';", true);
```

Comment: Use ScriptManager. Also make sure jQuery is loaded the time your script executes.

Comment: In last example I should have used .style.display=block; instead of show()

Comment: Sorry I did not tested that code, now I have tested code in the last example of my answer. I explained one more problem that was not javascript to get the element.

Comment: We can use html style tag to hide the panel with html rendered by asp.net, check my updated answer.

Comment: It is working. Thank you for your patience and your guidance, have a nice day! ( btw: I will delete the unnecessary comments )

Comment: You are welcome, I will too and update the answer accordingly